# Varaible types of data in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, post

I am currently designing a recipes website. I have fleshed out most of the 'edit' page, but one feature still eludes me.

How can I handle people "editing" the ingredients? Specifically, how can I handle the addition and removal of several ingredients when it comes time to make the POST?

My interface currently has edit buttons and an "add ingredient" button, as shown here:
[image: GUI Preview]

Here is a brief example:
A recipe currently has four ingredients: Bread, tomatoes, lettuce, bacon. If a user were to add a new ingredient (mayonnaise, for instance), and to edit the bread to be "wheat bread", **how can I pack all this data into a single POST?**

### EDIT: For clarification

I am not asking how I can reflect these changes in the database. That can be taken care of on the server side. My question is, how, on the *client side* can I pack these transaction-type changes into a single post message, which is sent back to the server.

Comment: you can do the editing with JS but if you actually want to save it you're going to have to use a server side script like php, ruby, etc.

Comment: this depends on which server side language/frameworks you are using.

Comment: Oh, for sure. This is a Django app under the hood. I'm not worried about saving the data. I can easily pick apart the POST on the server side. My real questions is how can I assemble the data on the client side to send to the server?

Comment: Maybe package it into a JSON object consisting of quanity, unit, and item description?

Comment: How can I pack a JSON object into a POST request?

Comment: That would be a job for [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: Is your actual question: "*How do I determine the fields that have been added or changed and only send those*"?

Comment: Fore more granular control over the AJAX request, use [`$.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) instead of `$.post()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of each ingredient as a js object.

```
//simplified for clarity
{ingredient: "blah blah blah"}

var ingredients = {
 [
   {ingredient: "1 Box of Macaroni"},
   {ingredient: "30 Ounces of tomato sauce"}
 ]
}
```

You can then `push` ingredients into this array of ingredients (when an ingredient is added) and post it over to the server with an AJAX request on save or append inputs to your form if you aren't using AJAX...